# How can fast to delete some records from a table that has 1b records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has more or less 1b records, and it keeps the data in 180 days, so I need to delete those records that more than 180 days.

Firstly, I just used the `delete` to delete records, and it was took almost 1h, and then, I tried to `creat table` everyday and saved the data into the table of the day, and `drop` the table that more than 180 days.

Is there a better way to delete those records, I don't think the second way of mine is a good to do this.

I'm sorry for my poor English, but please give me a hand!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you indexed the columns (columns in where clause) ? That might speed up the process.

Comment: 1. add index to the date column. 2. do deletion in small batches

Comment: I used `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on the columns of time, but it wasn't very help to this. @Sami

Comment: I have tried to delete 1k records every time until delete all the data what I neet to delete, and I used `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on the columns of time, it's faster, but not fast enough...@Squirrel

Comment: Which version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Standard @LesH

Comment: Might be time to consider an [edition upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution might be helpful.

- Change your database's `Recovery Mode to SIMPLE`
- Delete data in chunks

like:

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;


WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
//--Delete some small number of rows at a time
 DELETE TOP (10000)  LargeTable 
 WHERE readTime < dateadd(MONTH,-7,GETDATE())


SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
CHECKPOINT -- for simple recovery model


END
```

- change the Recovery mode back to full

Hope it  helps!

Comment: Thank you,I have tried this way, but I don't think it's fast enough.